# Ограничить position: fixed по ширине

Tags: html, css, position

Добрый день!

На сайте есть фиксированный блок, который прижат к правому нижнему углу.
Я хочу ограничить его с помощью max-width главного контейнера.

Т.е например чтобы на больших разрешениях блок не уходил за пределы max-width: 1440px.

Нашел следующее решение, но оно не работает если блок прижат к нижней части окна http://jsfiddle.net/Jayx/vFQpX/2/

```
 .content{
    background:#ccc;
    max-width:500px;
    margin:50px auto;
    position:relative;
}

.marker{
    position:absolute;
    width:200px;
    right:0;
}

.fixedmarker{
    background:#f00;
    color:#fff;
    position:fixed;
    width:200px;
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: Please translate into Russian or use http://stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, красиво решить вашу задачу не выйдет. Однако через @media можно изменять размер блока при достижении окном браузера определенный размеров:

```
@media (max-width: 1440px) {
    .fixedmarker{
        width:100px;
    }    
}
```